# How should we deal with off-topic questions with a lot of upvotes?

Tags: discussion, old-questions

I recently stumbled upon this question (*[Anyone out there using web2py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76809/anyone-out-there-using-web2py)*) which has a lot of upvotes.

I would say this question is off-topic since it is not a programming question.

But it has been asked more than ten years ago and has about 70 upvotes and more than 30k views.

So I have two questions:

1. Am I missing something and this question actually is not off-topic?
2. If it is off-topic: given that so many users seem to be interested in this question, should it stay open nevertheless or should it be closed?

Comment: It's off-topic, but back then anything went. VTC and move on. Or just wait. Now that it's here the meta-crowd will rage over it. Anything can happen.

Comment: It's closed now. Problem solved.

Comment: It's already closed by meta. Not sure if needs to be deleted, doesn't seem to be doing any harm.

Comment: It was already closed by a mod once, left closed after going through reopen review, and then reopened by other five users. Nuke it from orbit. It's the only way to be sure.